# How to update a string as htmlencoded string using update statement in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a update query, where I need to update the HTML encoded string in the database.
Below is the update statement -

```
 $model->update(array('CreatedDate','SmsText'));
```

Suppose if 'SmsText' contains
 `"A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>"`.
 I want it to be saved as
`A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;`.
I tried with the below query, but this did not work

$model->update(array('CreatedDate',encode('SmsText')));
How can I do this

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the update query you should write :-

```
$model->SmsText = Chtml::encode($model->SmsText);
```

And then call the update function like :-

```
$model->update('CreatedDate', 'SmsText');
```

I hope this resolves the issue.